# Javascript save variable to array and get values in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have JavaScript code like this:

```
var arrayku = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
{
  var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
  if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
  {
    return [i, sParameterName[0], sParameterName[1]]; //i is id, sParameterName[0] is first 2nd param, sParameterName[1] is third param
  }
}
```

The Question is how to:

1. Put variable `i`, `sParameterName[0]`, `sParameterName[1]` into array of key and value and I want variable `i` as the key.
2. How to get all value of `arrayku` in a loop?

Comment: [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Devi, your question isn't clear.  By "array of key and value" do you mean an Object, which is what Javascript uses for an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)?  Why can't you get all  the values of `arrayku` the same way you get all  the values of `sURLVariables`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add the elements to the array in the loop.

```
var arrayku = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
  var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
  if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
    arrayku.push( [i, sParameterName[0], sParameterName[1]]); //i is id, sParameterName[0] is first 2nd param, sParameterName[1] is third param
  }
}
console.log(arrayku);
```

Comment: hi epascarello, thanks for the answer, how to access and display arrayku?

Comment: It is a array of objects.... You access it like an Array? Not sure how you want to display it...